# consecutive calls to glDrawElements

Tags: c++, opengl-es, glsl

I am trying to draw a mesh with multiple textures. To do that, I seprate model in to sub models based on the textures.

Here is the code and explanation:

- Set up render program by line RenderCommon and SetProjectViewModel functions
- Render common only initializes buffers if they are not already.

  ```
   RenderCommon(object);
   SetProjectViewModel(m_basicProgramHandle, object, cam);
  ```
- Collect mesh and its submeshes by the fallowing for loop

  ```
  std::vector<Mesh*> meshes;
  meshes.push_back(object->m_mesh.get());
  for (int i = 0; i < (int)object->m_mesh->m_subMeshes.size(); i++)
    meshes.push_back(object->m_mesh->m_subMeshes[i]);
  ```
- Than the fallowing code is fore drawing each submesh with glDrawElements

  ```
    for (auto mesh : meshes)
    {
      GLuint offset = 0;
      glEnableVertexAttribArray(0); // Vertex
      glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, object->m_mesh-  >GetVertexSize(), 0);

      offset += 3 * sizeof(float);
      glEnableVertexAttribArray(1); // Normal
      glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, object->m_mesh->GetVertexSize(), (const void*)offset);

      offset += 3 * sizeof(float);
      glEnableVertexAttribArray(2); // Texture
      glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, object->m_mesh->GetVertexSize(), (const void*)offset);

      glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mesh->m_vboVertexId);

      RenderState rs = mesh->m_material->m_renderState;
      glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, rs.m_diffuseTexture);

      if (mesh->m_indexCount != 0)
      {
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, mesh->m_vboIndexId);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, mesh->m_indexCount, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, nullptr);
      }
      else
      {
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, mesh->m_vertexCount);
      }
  ```

Lets say there is a cube and two textures for its 6 faces. 1 face has a texture of 1 on it and other texture has 0 on it. With this setup if I draw only one item. Its fine. However if for loop draws 2 items than I saw only front and back faces with two different textures. Instead of 6 faces. That is each object is drawn but partially.

I check buffer and texture ids a hundred times ! they are correct. If I draw each buffer one by one than they are ok aswell. But if I draw them consecutively than they appears partially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems

> ```
> glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mesh->m_vboVertexId);
> ```

must appear before any of the fallowing code

> ```
> glEnableVertexAttribArray(0); // Vertex
> glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, object->m_mesh->GetVertexSize(), 0);
> ```